# How to exclude from the arrays with divs the a specific parent with children?

Tags: jquery

How to exclude from the arrays with divs the a specific parent by id with children?
I would like to get array with divs without id3 id4 id5 and p and h3.
I tried to use this, but it's not work: $('div').not('#id3'>'div p h3').css('background-color' : 'black');

```
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
  <div id="id1">
    <div id="id2">
      <div id="id3">
       <div id="id4">
         <div id="id5">
          <p>Text here</p><h3>Text here</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  <div></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('div:not(#id3, #id3 *)').css('background-color', 'green');
```

Also, you have typo in setting the css, it should be `.css('background-color', 'green')` instead of `.css('background-color' : 'black')`

```js
$('div:not(#id3, #id3 *)').css('background-color', 'green');
```

```css
div {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>A</div>
<div id="id1">id1
  <div id="id2">id2
    <div id="id3">id3
      <div id="id4">id4
        <div id="id5">id5
          <p>Text here</p>
          <h3>Text here</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>B</div>
```

Comment: Hi! This works as it should! I've never seen anything like it. Can I ask you how you guessed?

Comment: I have faced issues like this in past, so a little bit of experience always helps :p